# Correctly insert row into MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table created with:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Messages', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.Messages
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Messages
(
   Id            INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- primary key column
   Username      [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
   MessageType   [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
   Recepient     [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
   RecepientType [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
   Payload       [NVARCHAR](255),
   Stamp         DATETIME
);
GO
```

When I try to insert data into the table, an error happens.

Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Messages 
VALUES ('thin', 'message.broadcast', 'channelID', 'channel', 'test', '2019-07-23 15:19:08.960697828 +0300 EEST m=+14.232534538')
```

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

Is this happening because my datetime needs to formatted for SQL Server, or do I need to describe the primary key differently in to order to have SQL Server autogenerate values for this column?

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: seems your ID value is not inserted. I mean, at least the first value should be an integer, and you have six values totally where it should exist seven.

Comment: You are trying to insert 6 values in the table with 7 columns

Comment: your table has 7 columns, so you need to specify 7 values in your insert statement. If your Id is an identity then you can leave this field out

Comment: maybe you supposed to create your table with column `Id` as `identity` ?

Comment: Best practice is to specify the column names in the insert statement. It protects against schema changes (new column order for example). It would also help you in the case where your columns do not coincide with the supplied values to more easily figure out the syntax error.

Comment: As noted in answer by Michael Turzyn below you are missing `IDENTITY(1,1)` from your table definition or need to insert specific value for ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider change stamp column to timestamp and id to identity column like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Messages', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Messages
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Messages
(
   Id        INT    NOT NULL   IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, -- primary key column
   Username      [NVARCHAR](50)  NOT NULL,
   MessageType   [NVARCHAR](50)  NOT NULL,
   Recepient     [NVARCHAR](50)  NOT NULL,
   RecepientType [NVARCHAR](50)  NOT NULL,
   Payload       [NVARCHAR](255),
   Stamp         [timestamp] NOT NULL -- timestamp column
);
GO
```

Then, simply insert your data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Messages 
   (Username, MessageType, Recepient,   RecepientType,   Payload)
VALUES('thin', 'message.broadcast', 'channelID', 'channel', 'test')
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing ID in your insert statement.

If you want ID to be autogenerated you need to use `IDENTITY(1, 1)` where you choose seed and increment step in place of 1's.

If you don't want to autogenerate ID, then you need to include it in `INSERT` statements.

Column definition should be:

```
Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score 2):

Although your error clears that 6 values are passing for 7 columns.

You need to insert specifically column names.

```
   Insert into  Messages ( Username , MessageType , Recepient , RecepientType ,  Payload  , Stamp  )
   values ('thin', 'message.broadcast', 'channelID', 'channel', 'test', '2019-07-23 15:19:08.960697828 +0300 EEST m=+14.232534538')
```

After that also you are facing an issue which is corrected by this.

If Id want to be inserted automatic, then make it idenity like `Id int identity(1, 1) not null`

Comment: Is not strictly necessary, but it's very recommended, indeed.

Comment: it is good practice to mention your column names in insert statement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add as many columns in your insert statement as there are columns in your table, except for identity fields.

Without your Id as identity, you need this

```
insert into Messages (Id, Username, MessageType, Recepient, RecepientType,  Payload, Stamp)
values (1, 'thin', 'message.broadcast', 'channelID', 'channel', 'test', '2019-07-23 15:19:08.960697828 +0300 EEST m=+14.232534538')
```

This means its up to you to determine the next value for your Id every time.

Better is to create the Id field as identity like this

```
Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
```

Now you can simply do this (the Id value will be automatic incremented now)

```
insert into  Messages (Username, MessageType, Recepient, RecepientType,  Payload, Stamp)
values ('thin', 'message.broadcast', 'channelID', 'channel', 'test', '2019-07-23 15:19:08.960697828 +0300 EEST m=+14.232534538')
```

Using column names in your insert also has the benefit that you can put them in any order you like